# Codeigniter HTML form - can't click on input fields

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, for-loop

just wondering what I've done wrong here. I have following HTML form for use with Codeigniter with several dropdowns.

Beyond the first SELECT element I cannot click on any of the input boxes without it jumping to the original SELECT dropdown and the other SELECT drop downs display result only momentarily before I jump back to first SELECT drop down again.

I'm guessing I've done something very simply wrong here in the looping for the first SELECT drop down, but I just can't see it.

NB. Also, source code is perfectly correct - just the form's behaviour that isn't...

Any ideas?

```
                <!-- Admin Products -->
                <div>
<?php if(COUNT($form) > 0):?>
<?php for($i = 0;$i < COUNT($form);$i++):?>
            <div id="message"></div>

            <?=validation_errors()?>

            <?=form_open('admin/form/' . $this->uri->segment(3))?>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Fill in form</legend><br>

                    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?=$form[$i]['id']?>"><br>

                    <input name="strId" size="30" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('strId');?>"><br>

                    <label><?=$form[$i]['text_name']?>

                    <select name="line">
<?php if(COUNT($lines) > 0):?>
<?php for($x = 0;$x < COUNT($lines);$x++):?>
                        <option><?=$lines[$x]['line']?></option>
<?php endfor;?>
<?php endif;?>
                    </select><br>

                    <input name="new_line" size="30" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('new_line');?>"><br>

                    <select name="product">
<?php if(COUNT($products) > 0):?>
<?php for($y = 0;$y < COUNT($products);$y++):?>
                        <option><?=$products[$y]['product']?></option>
<?php endfor;?>
<?php endif;?>
                    </select><br>

                    <label>New product

                    <input name="new_product" size="30" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('new_product');?>"><br>

                    <input name="size" size="30" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('size');?>"><br>

                    <input name="unit" size="30" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('unit');?>"><br>

                    <label><?=$form[$i]['brand_brandName']?>

                    <select name="brand">
<?php if(COUNT($brands) > 0):?>
<?php for($z = 0;$z < COUNT($brands);$z++):?>
                        <option><?=$brands[$z]['brand']?></option>
<?php endfor;?>
<?php endif;?>
                    </select><br>

                    <label>New brand

                    <input name="new_brand" size="30" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('new_brand');?>"><br><br>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </fieldset><!-- End of fieldset tag -->
            </form><!-- End of form tag -->
<?php endfor;?>
<?php endif;?>
                </div><!-- End Admin Products -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have to close the label tags:  `<label></label>`

Comment: I knew it would be something so simple! Thanks! D'oh!